# passing date and time to SQL server using C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, types, syntax

Can you please help me:

How do I pass String dateAndTime = "2/2/2012 5:57:00 pm" to SQL server using C#?

I was passing it as a String but obviously SQL does not like the syntax. it gives me an error:

Wrong syntax near 5:

Comment: are you wanting to pass the current time if so the below answer is not a good one

Comment: no time when a user store records.

Answer (score 6):

Never pass dates as string, but use the proper datetime datatype. Look up commands and parameters instead of creating SQL statements in code. Google SqlCommand

EDIT: I was on my phone yesterday. Here is a better answer:

```
int GetNumberOfItemsAfterDate(DateTime dateInput) {
    // Create a sql statement with a parameter (@FirstDate)
    string sql = @"SELECT Count(*)
                   FROM   table
                   WHERE  table.date >= @FirstDate";

    // Create a sql connection
    // Always use the using statement for this
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

        // Create a sql command
        // Always use the using statement for this
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) {

            // Pass the dateinput argument to the command, and let
            // the .NET Framework handle the conversion properly!
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCommand("FirstDate", dateInput));

            // No need for calling .Close() or .Dispose() - the using
            // statements handle that for us
            return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much context in your question, but I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Parse("2/2/2012 5:57:00 pm");
//Do something with dateAndTime.
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to DateTime

Use this in SQL Query string:

```
 " Convert(datetime, '" + dateAndTime + ")"
```

SQL Query Syntax Example:

```
main.received_date > Convert(datetime,'12/28/2011')
```

**Edit1: More Complete Example**

```
void int DatabaseQuery(string dateInput)
{
    query = @"
          SELECT rank=Count(*)
          FROM    table
          WHERE table.date Convert(datetime,'" + dateInput + "')"

        DbConnection cn = some Database connection
        cn.Open();

        DbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        var reason = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
        return reason.ToInt();
}
```

**Edit2:**

It may be better to pass the dateTime as a true `DateTime` and then use `dateTime.ToString()` to ensure correct variable is passed.

Comment: you can do this on the database end and just pass the sql query as a string

Comment: Never pass dates as strings. Actually, never pass any parameters directly as sql. Always let the framework do the conversion and insertion.

Comment: @atombland Correct, It's a bad practice to. My example though showed how to take a string input and let the database side convert it. However, its prone to exceptions unless you do the conversion to `DateTime` first and pass it as a parameter like your example.